# Creating a simple web browser for Mac OSX

Tags: macos

I need to create a simple application that works as a web browser. No buttons, URL bars - just an application that directs the user to a webpage where he can then navigate. On Windows I used Microsoft Visual Studio for this task - I created a Windows Forms application and then dragged the WebBrowser form from the toolbox. How can this be achieved in Mac OSX?

Thanks in forward :)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS you should use NSWebView object.

Comment: Thanks! Upon some further research, I also found that this could be done with Xcode using WebKit.framework